# Are there any programs that can do non-orthogonal CI?

Tags: configuration-interaction, nonorthogonal-ci, valence-bond-theory

Could you list any programs that can do non-orthogonal CI please?

Answer (score 7):

To start with, we do have:

1. LUCIA, a Correlation Program, 2019, developed by Kähler and Olsen. [Nonorthogonal internally contracted multi-configurational perturbation theory](http://doi.org/10.1063/1.4999218) and [Dynamic correlation for nonorthogonal reference states](http://doi.org/10.1063/1.5049706).
2. [Q-CHEM](https://manual.q-chem.com/5.2/Ch7.S4.html).
3. [GronOR](http://gronor.org): Massively parallel and GPU- accelerated non-orthogonal configuration interaction for large molecular systems.
4. TURTLE, an Ab ignition VB/VBSCF Program, 1988-2000, developed by J. Verbeek, J. H. Langenberg, C. P. Byrman, F. Dijkstra, and J. H. van Lenthe.
5. ... continue the list ...